# Nothing Happening when trying to write to file on SD card android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to write to an SD card:

```
File dir =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder");
    if(!dir.exists())
    {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    String filename= "MyDoople.txt";
    try
    {
        File f = new File(dir+File.separator+filename);

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                fOut);
        myOutWriter.append("Mytest");
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Text Updated",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However when I run my app, and then go check in the SD card, there is nothing there. Why am I not seeing the file that I created? I am using android jellybean  4.1 and have added the write permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: In your catch, change `printStackTrace` to `Log.e("tag", "message", Exception)` in order to display the error if there is one.

Comment: Will it not display the error otherwise?

Comment: When trying to add that line it complains about the last parameter Exception

Comment: Replace Exception by e which is the exception object's name.

Comment: I did that and nothing seems to be going wrong, also "text updated" shows on my screen

Comment: maybe I just can't see it because there is no file manager on the nexus?

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you're writing to the folder "MyFolder" under **primary external storage**.

What is the device you are using? Does it have interal storage in additional to sd card? If yes, then your file is written to the internal storage, but not the sd card.

**Edit:**
To access SD Card, you simply replace `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with the sd card path.

It is not an easy task to find the path of SD card.

One method is to use `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)`, the first element of the returned value would be the same `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, the second element would be somewhere of the sdcard.

**However**, could be depending on your android version, the directory returned could be a sub-directory on the sd card, i.e. your application specific directory instead of the root of SD card. You have to check and manually change it if you want to find the root directory.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: The device is a nexus 5

Comment: and yes it has internal storage in addition to sd card

Comment: How could I make it write to the SD card?

Comment: added as edit on how to find SD card folder, it is not a straight forward task on Android

Comment: AS does not like the context variable? what should this be set as?

Comment: If you are inside Activity, use `this `

Comment: It still doesn't like it.